# Netbeans on 17.10 looks ugly

Tags: 17.10, netbeans

After installing Netbeans 8.2 looks ugly. It's something wrong with visual theme.
[image: Netbeans on U17.10]

I tried to install it through Ubuntu Store as well as downloaded from the official site and executed provided script.

How can I fix it?

Comment: LOL, isn't that how it's supposed to look?  I don't use eclipse, but that looks fine to me.  Would you elaborate on the problem?